# Sephardim saying Al Mizvas Tefillin beracha?

Tags: tefilla, minhag, blessing, tefilin

Is there any sephardim that say the "Al Mitzvas Tefillin" beracha for the Tefillin shel Rosh? Are they allowed to say a beracha for it?

I am asking because in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aRbYaOYFmyE), which demonstrates how to put on tefillin the Sephardi and ashkenazi way, and when they show you the sephardi way it says the beracha "Al Mitzvas Tefillin" and "Baruch Shem Kevod..." when the sephardi put on the Shel Rosh.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about a case where there was no Hefsek between the two Tefillin?

Comment: avinadav, there is no Sefardi in that video. It's just Ashkenazim (the first wraps "out" aka Nusach Sefard, and the second kid wraps "in" aka Nusach Ashkenaz).

Comment: that kid was clearly sephardi, dont know what you're talking about

Comment: Not everyone who is tan is sephardi, avinadav...

Comment: achi, that kid's tefillin was sephardi, and he had a tallis on

Comment: What makes his tefillin sephardi? And sephardim don't have a monopoly on tallitot. Many ashkenazim wear a tallis when wearing tefillin.

Comment: but not until they are married, unless you're a german jew

Comment: @avinadaveliezer FWIW the Rav was of the opinion that all Jews, even Ashkenazim, should wear a tallit g'dolah for prayer unless they have a custom to specifically refrain from wearing it until their weddings.

Comment: Maybe Hasidic Sephardim might do this. I dunno.

Answer (score 1):

It is not something we do normally. What I was told was, we only say the blessing for the head when we have spoken between putting on the arm and putting on the head.
So after the blessing for the arm until the meditation of the finger wrapping is silence. Of course we sit with the arm and stand for the head.
I have a mixed family one side does Sephardic and the other Hassidic. So Tefillin I ask lots of questions as a young man. Now am old and it still is a great blessing, never lost its sparkle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Can you clarify with an [edit] whether the info in its first sentence is Sephardic-based?

Answer (score 0):

See SA O C 25, 5:

> ויניח של יד תחילה ויברך להניח תפילין ואחר כך יניח של ראש  ולא יברך כי אם ברכה אחת לשתיהן
>
> Rabbi Yosef Karo says clearly to bless one blessing only for the two.

The Beur Halacha explained that Rishonim discussed this rule, an that the Gain Mivilna ruled as the Mechaber. Acharonim Sefaradim as Kaf Hachayim follow the Shulchan Aruch.

No doubt about the Sephardic custom. I heard from an old litwak that in Lita, most people blessed one blessing only, may be because of the GRA opinion.

Comment: `No doubt about the Sephardic custom.` This isnt a sentence. I assume you meant to write "There is no doubt about the Sehardic custom" and are assuming that no Sephardim make a blessing on the "shel rosh". While this may or may not be true, it is certainly not proven by your answer which cites no sources regarding Sephardic custom(s).

Comment: Many Sephardic authorities throughout the ages have disagreed with the ShA on a variety of topics. Sephardim are not a homogeneous group, and they have many differing customs. A quote form the ShA is a prompt for a conversation about Sephardic practice; not the end of conversation.

Comment: Note that the OP asked "are there any Sephardim". Even if the vast majority of Sephardim follow this ruling of the ShA, this answer could still be totally incorrect.